# chaining a:not(x)::before selector

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have have a nav with links animated with css (draws a line on top of element)

```css
a, a.nav-link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #594922;
}
a.nav-link:hover{
    color: #4dd897 
}
a.nav-link::before{
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    background: #594922;
    display: block;
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1)
}
a.nav-link:hover::before {
  transform-origin: right top;
  transform: scale(1, 1)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link">abcde</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link">b</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link">c</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do now is to ignore the animation on the first link, I tried adding the :not(:first-of-type) but it breaks the whole animation

```css
a, a.nav-link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #594922;
}
a.nav-link:hover{
    color: #4dd897 
}
a.nav-link:not(:first-of-type)::before{
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    background: #594922;
    display: block;
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1)
}
a.nav-link:hover::before {
  transform-origin: right top;
  transform: scale(1, 1)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link">abcde</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link">b</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-link">c</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would appreciate any help, Thanx

Comment: It is the first li you want to select, not the first a inside li

Comment: Of course `a.nav-link:not(:first-of-type)` breaks everything, because with that, _none_ of your links get selected any more. They all are the first (and last, and only) element of that type within their respective parent, which is the LI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select every li element that is not the first one and apply the styling to the nav-links in there. Need to just put li:not(:first-of-type) in front of your css selectors like below. You could also use li:not(:first-child). The reason being is that the 'a' elements aren't siblings of each other, they're wrapped in li elements. The li elements are siblings of each other so when you put the :first-of-type on the a element that is always just the one element that is inside of the li which is why it removes it for all of them not just the first one.

```
li:not(:first-of-type) a.nav-link::before{
content: '';
height: 1px;
background: #594922;
display: block;
transform: scale(0, 1);
transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1)}

li:not(:first-of-type) a.nav-link:hover::before {transform-origin: right top;transform: scale(1, 1)}
```

Comment: I tried it and it still breaks the effect:(

Comment: actually I just realized that ```li:not(:first-of-type) .nav-link::before``` works, just had to erase the a

Comment: you also have to put in front of these lines as well a.nav-link:hover::before {
  transform-origin: right top;
  transform: scale(1, 1)
}